# Scheduled Email in Google-App-Engine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

What app-engine API will be used for sending scheduled email? I want the app to send email weekly.

Answer (score 3):

For scheduling see:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

For example:

```
<cron>
 <url>/reports/weekly</url>
 <description>Mail out a weekly report</description>
 <schedule>every saturday 09:00</schedule>
 <timezone>Asia/Tokyo</timezone>
</cron>
```

Then configure a servlet to handle the request to */reports/weekly*.  If you have many to send, you may want to set up the handling servlet to use a [taskQueue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)

For mailing see:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/